# Getting content from opening associated file Android SDK

Tags: android, file, android-intent, file-association

So, I am associating a particular file type with my app and I want to be able to make it so that when a file of that type is opened, the app opens and is able to retrieve the information from the file. How would I go about doing this? I know I can associate the file by using the following:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.shrt" android:mimeType="*/*"  />
```

Of course the code is in the manifest file in an intent filter, but getting the text of the file is what is leaving me stuck. I couldn't find any article relating to the subject(only one, which had no solutions).

Answer (score 0):

> I am associating a particular file type with my app

No, you are not. You are attempting to associate a *file extension* with your app. This will be less and less useful over time, as Android moves further away from files and more towards content served by `ContentProvider`s, for better access control.

You are welcome to associate file extensions with your app, but you also need to consider adopting a suitable MIME type and supporting other schemes (e.g., `content`), or perhaps getting away from thinking about files in general.

> getting the text of the file is what is leaving me stuck

In `onCreate()`, call `getIntent().getData()` to get the `Uri` of the file. From there, you can call `getPath()` on the `Uri` to get the path to the file (to get rid of the `file://` scheme). At that point, it should be standard Java file I/O.

Comment: By file type I was referring to file extension. Thank you for clarifying that, though the tone from the message seemed negative. That being besides the point, thank you I will try this as a solution.